# Teamcity nightly build only if new build exists

Tags: deployment, teamcity, build-process

Is it possible to configure TeamCity 8+ to only deploy to the server if the version/build has changed. Our issue currently is we are deploying nightly but some nights there are no new changes and we do not want TeamCity to deploy.

I've searched their documentation and google but can not seem to find anything that talks about doing this. Wondering if it can be done?

Comment: Is your team city hooked up to a source control repository? Because then you can set it up to only build if teamcity detects any new changes.

Comment: Yes it is using Stash for git repositories.

Comment: Where in TeamCity can you set that parameter?

Comment: Try this http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/version_control_integration.html and http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Roots

Comment: Also this might help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434456/teamcity-where-is-the-automation?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a schedule trigger that is set to run every night at 1:00 AM or something like that, right?

You can set it up to only run if there are changes to the repositories it uses, or any subset of them. You can even make it only run if there are changes to certain files or folders in a repository.

Look in the settings for your [schedule trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers). If you set it up this way, it won't even trigger if there are no changes.